# Al Netilas Yadayim in morning and after bathroom

Tags: halacha, blessing, netilat-yadayim-washing, bathroom

Are you supposed to say the bracha al netilas yadayim after doing negel vasser after waking up or going to the bathroom?

Answer (score 2):

You are supposed to say the Berachah upon washing your hands in the morning. ([Shulchan Aruch O"C 4:1](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=45&hilite=))

It seems from the Shulchan Aruch ([O"C 7:1-2](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=9729&st=&pgnum=57)) that you do not need to make a Berachah even if you find that you need to wash your hands after using the bathroom, because you are only required to wash then for cleanliness - in fact, you may not need to wash at all, depending on the condition of your hands afterwards.  The GR"A (ibid., S"K 2) explains that this is because the sages enacted the law of washing upon rising because we are like a new creation, as well as before eating (although he doesn't explain this last point), but not for any other purpose.

However, I have heard that, according to some, you are supposed to say the Berachah after using the bathroom, depending on what you were doing in the bathroom, I have not seen a source for this idea.

Comment: IIRC the gra is referencing a teshuvat harashba where he says the bracha is on waking up like a new being. This opinion argues on nearly all other rishonim (see for example rambam) that you need to make one when you wash for davening (all three prayers). So the beit yosef ruled safek brachot lehakel and only to make one in the morning, but it would have to be on the one for davening as well which would mean post bathroom.

Comment: @DoubleAA And the Ramban and the Rosh.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin and them on which side

Comment: @DoubleAA http://beta.hebrewbooks.org/tursa.aspx?a=oc_x20

Comment: @DoubleAA see also the Beis Yosef there D"H Kasuv

Comment: @DoubleAA You're saying one says "al netilas yadayim" when washing before davening and/or after going to the bathroom?!

Comment: @SAH Most Rishonim thought so (at least for some permutation of what you did in the bathroom and how soon you'd be praying), and with them many medieval Jews did that.

Comment: @DoubleAA Thanks. Do you know if anyone [who washes and says asher yotzar after every bathroom use] does it today?

Comment: @SAH I would guess not for post-bathroom. Rarely you may find someone who says Al Netilas Yadayim when washing before prayer.

Comment: The source for this idea is very explicit in Kitzur Shulchan Aruch: https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.2.7?lang=bi  However, I have a hard time to understand his ruling since we do say berachos during the day without using the bathroom, as long as it is not bal t'shaktzu.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught that the "best" way is to wash negel vaser in bed without a bracha, then go to the bathroom, get dressed or at least be decent, wash again, say al netilas yadayim, say asher yotzar, and then say the rest of brochas. I used to do it a different way that involved only washing once, as I think a lot of people do. I don't remember when you say the bracha if done that way, but I think it is still at the end.